# How do I refer to a register in a foreach loop in LLVM?

Tags: foreach, llvm

I'm currently trying to define registers of architecture I work with via TableGen. There're supposed to be 2 computation blocks XR and YR and a pseudoblock XYR referring to them. For example XYR3 is a vector pseudoregister embracing X3 and Y3.

```
// Classes for registers of my namespace.

class TigerSHARCReg<bits<5> num, string n, list<string> altNames = []> :
  Register<n, altNames>
{
  field bits<5> Num = num;
  let Namespace = "TigerSHARC";
}

class TigerSHARCVReg<bits<5> num, string n, list<TigerSHARCReg> subregs, list<SubRegIndex> indices = []> :
  RegisterWithSubRegs<n, subregs>
{
  field bits<5> Num = num;
  let Namespace = "TigerSHARC";
    let SubRegIndices = indices;
}

class TigerSHARCSubRegIndex<int size, int offset> : SubRegIndex<size, offset>
{
    let Namespace = "TigerSHARC";
}

// === === ===

// XR registers and XR register class
foreach num = 0-31 in
def XR#num : TigerSHARCReg<num, "XR"#num>;

def XR : RegisterClass<"TigerSHARC", [i32, f32], 32, 
    (sequence "XR%u", 0, 31)>;


// YR registers and YR register class
foreach num = 0-31 in
def YR#n : TigerSHARCReg<num, "YR"#num>;

def YR : RegisterClass<"TigerSHARC", [i32, f32], 32, 
    (sequence "YR%u", 0, 31)>;

// There only two subregisters in each XYR
def XYRsub0 : TigerSHARCSubRegIndex<1, 0>;
def XYRsub1 : TigerSHARCSubRegIndex<1, 0>;


// XYR registers and XYR register class
foreach num = 0-31 in
def XYR#num : TigerSHARCVReg<0, "XYR0", [XR#num, YR#num], [XYRsub0, XYRsub1]>;

def XYR : RegisterClass<"TigerSHARC", [v2i32], 32, (sequence "XYR%u", 0, 31)>;
```

The problem is in theese lines:

```
foreach num = 0-31 in
def XYR#num : TigerSHARCVReg<0, "XYR0", [XR#num, YR#num], [XYRsub0, XYRsub1]>;
```

"#" concats only strings so [XR#num, YR#num] is incorrect notation. I've tried XR[num] but it doesn't seem to work either.

Is there a way to refer to an existing register in a loop?

Also, am I even doing it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like that instead of [XR#num, YR#num] one should use [!cast< MyTypeReg >("XR"#n), !cast< MyTypeReg >("YR"#n)]. !cast(a) looks in a symbol table string a.